# JXCore quitting socket.io/express server strait after starting it?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, socket.io, nodes, jxcore

I created a basic socket.io express server from the Docs' on socket.io's website, but when I package the jS file and etc into the .jxp file, running it just returns the terminal prompt.

```
ozziepeck11$ jx server.jx 
ozziepeck11$
```

Whereas Node will run it fine, can I adapt my code to work with JXCore or is JXCore just not designed for this? But it would be pretty pointless.. The multithreading feature of JXCore would make a socket.io/express server so much better.

Comment: Any one know? how to fix this?